# Apache compressing server communication

Tags: apache, compression

It's the other way around as usual. It's possible to compress the communication between Apache and a J2EE server even though the client might not compressing the message?

Browser <- compressed or not -> Apache <- always compressed -> Jetty

Answer (score 1):

Actually, as far as I know, AJP is always *uncompressed*. It's assumed that your web and application servers are "close" enough (in terms of network topology) to each other that compression is not useful, and just slows things down from the extra CPU processing.

If you're using HTTP between Apache and Jetty, then you can configure compression, yes, though I've not use Jetty and can't tell you how to configure that.

Comment: The problem is compressing the communication even though the client is telling the J2EE server to not compress the content.

Comment: @icCube: The client doesn't talk to the app server directly---all the client's interactions are mediated by the web server. So it's just up to the web server to request compression, and for the app server to support it.

Comment: for this particular scenario the client does not support compression (it's Excel using XMLA protocol - SOAP).